# Modify abstract factory design pattern for two-level factory creation

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have been working with C# 4.0 creating a code-base to process N files, at the beginning of the process that was the requirement, now the requirement changed and I need to process group of files, so we can say we have "**processes**" and every process has his own group of files:

I.E.:

Process1 { 4 files}

Process2 { 10 files}

Process3 { 23 files}

...

I have implemented the abstract factory design pattern for the initial requirement, so my factory receives the name of the file and with that I create the concrete instance of the class that process that specific file, now I need to adapt the pattern to at first create an Instance of the **Process** and with that instance create instances of the specific objects to process each file, I am trying to get something like this:

```
var processInstance = processFactory.GetInstance(processId);

processInstance.Method1(params);

var fileProcessor = processInstance.GetFileProcessorInstance(fileId);
fileProcessor.Method1(params);
fileProcessor.Method2(params);

processInstance.Method2(params);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. Can you explain what aspect of this is not working for you?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior yes, my current implementation of the abstract factory pattern just take in count the idea of "files", does not take in count the idea of "processes" and its associated "files".

Comment: Okay, so when you tried to change it to take into account this new concept, what specific programming problem did you run into?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Well, I'm very new to this design pattern and I have no idea how to create the two factories, are just two factories and call one inside the other? or exists any specific form to design the classes?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what aspect of this you're struggling with. Have you tried to create the factory pattern you're describing? If so, what isn't working? If not, there's not really much we can do for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the two factories and use a co-ordinator/orchestrator to control the interaction between the two. This is essentially what you're code sample is doing anyway.

I wouldn't compose a factory with another factory. Seems wrong to me.

If you make your co-ordinator/orchestrator dependent on the abstract factories' interfaces, everything's nice and testable, loosely coupled and reasonably SOLID.